# Case Sensitivity in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

In crystal Reports 8.5, I need to make first letter upper case and remaining lower case.

For example if I have data from Sql Server as  `GURUKIRAN VASUDEV NAYAK` it should display in report as `Gurukiran Vasudev Nayak`

Is it Possible? If possible how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try the ProperCase function. Create a Formula Field and write the following code

```
ProperCase({Command.Field})
```

replace the "Command" with the name of the database command and the "Field" with the name of the database field. To use the Formula Field, drag and drop it onto the report.

I don't know for sure if the 8.5 version contains the above function, but if it doesn't try the following SQL Server function http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/02/01/sql-server-udf-function-to-convert-text-string-to-title-case-proper-case/

Answer (score 1):

Try the `ProperCase` function. Create a Formula Field and write the following code

```
ProperCase({table.name})
```

`I LOVE MY INDIA`
result: `I Love My India`